# Webcomics/manhwa/manhua (not manga) about a hero who reincarnates as a noble lady

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

It may be a discontinued one but I remember that the former hero was a woman (gender bender & yet not; she was dressed as a male and was a holy knight), at the start upon defeating the demon lord has cursed him to reincarnate into a noble lady...

Upon the mc awakening she found that the ex-host was in a coma and also witnessed her own funeral (ex-body) and that her new body's mother-in-law  was planning to marry her away and that she was probably in cahoots with the demon lord (caused the ex-host to fall into a coma as a sacrifice).

Then she proposed a knight captain a deal in order to escape this marriage and deal with her mother-in-law. She was probably a duke's daughter.

Answer (score 3):

*[This Girl is a Little Wild](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=152875)* (2018) seems consistent with what you've described.

[image]

Synopsis:

> As he was being defeated, the Demon King used the last of his strength to curse Sir Roel, the legendary captain of the Holy Knights, into the body of a weak girl.
>
> Roel — who was a woman to begin with! — tired of her former life and unable to return to her original body, decides to live a luxurious life as Sila Epheria, the noble daughter whose soul got swapped with hers.
>
> Things don't go according to plan when her new family puts her in danger, forcing her to find a way to prove her true identity...
> Will Roel/Sila be able to live a quiet life as she wishes? Or is there something more to the new life she's received?

Comment: If this answer is correct, please upvote it and mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark just beneath the voting arrows.